# The newly added field's value not saved in db by magento

Tags: database, magento, model, controller, block

In Magento I created a new module as like the customer module.

Everything will be fine.

In my module there are some additional fields, but the values are not being saved into the db.

Only particular fields save into db.

I have not created a setup file as in the core part.

Do I require a setup file? And if yes how may I do it please?

How to set the default entities.

Answer (score 4):

delete cache . 
And if problem exists.
Refer [Link 1](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field).
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This worked! My cache was disabled but for some reason on some occasion you still need to go flush it yourself.
Thanks for this!